Is there an analog circuit that rounds voltage or current to digital-like values?
Is there a simpler circuit than basically using an ADC followed by a DAC for this?

Why would you?  What's the goal?   How many bits do you want to have?

Every digital circuit is an analog circuit if you look at it closely enough.

@jre for example let's say I have a power supply that should deliver 1, 2 or 5 volts but due to some other factors is off by up to 10% in any direction, yet I still would like to know in a simple way which of the three settings was selected

@thephoton indeed, and every analog circuit is a digital circuit with a very high resolution in some way

@TobiasKienzler, Either a) look at the knob rather than the output; or b) just use an ADC. What's the motivation to make your life harder by not using an ADC?

@thephoton I don't oppose using and ADC, my question was if that's the easiest way and as the answers indicate window comparators are enough

@TobiasKienzler, use enough window comparators and you've reinvented the flash ADC.

@thephoton yes indeed, I guess it's a blurry line

You could use a number of window comparators to divide a voltage range into discrete parts.
This is pretty much how the popular LM3914 Dot/Bar display driver works in dot mode, it has 10 comparators and turns on a different output depending on what part of the range the input voltage is in. It actually turns on all of the comparators up to the level of the input voltage to make a bar graph, and then for dot mode it has some extra decoding to only select the highest output. For a few steps this might not be too hard to implement on your own, but it might just be easiest to use one of these ICs.

Perfect, thanks!

Probably the easiest (and cheapest, or close to cheapest) way to do what you suggest is to use an MCU with an on-board ADC. Based on this comment:

let's say I have a power supply that should deliver 1, 2 or 5 volts
but due to some other factors is off by up to 10% in any direction,
yet I still would like to know in a simple way which of the three
settings was selected

MCUs with 10 or 12-bit ADCs are cheap and plentiful, and the firmware is easy. Just initialize and enter an infinite loop of taking ADC readings, doing comparisons, and setting output port pins.

Two analog comparators can be combined in a circuit called a window comparator.  The output is in one digital state when the input voltage is between two setpoint voltage values, and in the other digital state when the input voltage is either greater than or less than the window range.  The output digital state can drive a resistive voltage divider to produce any desired DC level for that window.  Depending on how many windows you want, this can add up to a lot of parts.

Start charging some capacitor linearly with current source and at the same time run a counter.
Compare the capacitor voltage with your measured analog signal.
Once the capacitor voltage is higher than measured analog signal stop the counter.
The number in counter is digital value of measured analog signal.
